# cellForRowAtIndexPath not call during device rotation

Tags: ios, uitableview, delegates

I have a UITableView with some delegate methods.During load for the first time it's all ok, but during the rotation I saw that the method **cellForRowAtIndexPath** doesn't recall. Why?
My delegate method are:

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
  numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
       //.....
   }

-(CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
     //......
 }
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView
     cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

     //...This method is not called during the rotation of the device...

  }

  - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
      //.......
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to refresh table data manually after the rotation occurs using `[tableView reloadData]` within `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` method.

Answer (score 0):

That method is only called when the cell is about to become visible on the screen and the table requests it. Once it is in the view, it will not be called again until it has scrolled out of view and then back.

You have 3 options for handling the rotation:

- Use AutoLayout
- Use Springs & Struts
- Override layoutSubviews (which will get called on a rotation)

What you choose will depend on how complex your cell layout is. Also, make sure the table resizes on the rotation, otherwise the cells won't see a size change.